# Send post request with content type

Tags: unity, networking, php

I used a php server to communicate with my unity application . I want to send post data with content type so that my php server can use the approriate variable for the content type , for example if i send post request with content type "file" , my php server can use $_FILES[][] instead of $_POST[], and i am a beginner and i'm too skeptical to use $_POST[] to handle upload request from unity application to server .

My best guess is that i must use something from [WWWForm](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/WWWForm.html) to achieve it , but in my opinion the documentation isn't friendly enough for beginner like me . Can someone here lend me a hand to achieve this ? (sending post request with content type)

Oh , also , i'm sorry for too much using php in my example , below is how i achieve it in html, i can achieve it in html by using something similar to this code :
(this html send POST request to upload a pictures with "file" as it content type)

```html
<form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<label>
Browse Image   
<input type="file" name="pictures" style="display:none">
</label><br>
<button name="upload">
Upload Now
</button>
</form>
```

Please forgive me if my english is too bad , thank you .

Comment: it looks to me like you want the [MultipartFormFileSection](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Networking.MultipartFormFileSection-ctor.html) — how have you tried using this in your Unity code so far?

Comment: @iam1515 2242t The documentation page you linked to really should answer your question. It has simple example code. If you are having trouble understanding it, please explain what part you are confused by.